# 302 in JQuery Mobile App

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile app. This app is currently running on localhost. I am relying on some services hosted on some of my backend servers. When I run a query, I noticed in fiddler that I am getting a 302. This 302 is causing my service call to fail.

If I copy-and-paste the URL of the service in my browser window, everything works fine. Here is my JQuery code

```
$.ajax({
  url: GetServiceUrl(),
  type: "GET",
  data: vm,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: service_Succeeded,
  error: service_Failed
});

function service_Succeeded(result) {
    alert("received!");
}

function service_Failed() {
  alert("oops");
}

function GetServiceUrl() {
  var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/services/endpoint";
  return url;
}
```

Why am I getting a 302 from my app?

Thank you

Comment: are you sending a `GET` request to a server which requests `POST` request?

Answer (score 0):

your service is sending a redirect request. Maybe you require a login?